# how can I use free form entry id for fetching data on different pages?

Tags: solspace-freeform

Got the entry id but don't know how to use this to fetch the data on different pages.

Comment: plz do some  hlp...

Comment: Why have you asked this question twice? Please delete one of the questions. Jim Wyse and I have both given you a correct answer (although I didn't know you had to add the form_id param). This is an unbelievably simply question that is directly in the Freeform documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you have redirected to a page capturing the entry_id.
i.e. 
`return="some/template/%%entry_id%%`

which would give you /some/template/456

On that page use the {exp:freeform:entries} tag and set the parameter, entry_id="{segment_3}"

```
{exp:freeform:entries entry_id="{segment_3}" form_id="111"}
```

With that you should have access to all the data for that entry.
don't forget to also set the form_id parameter.

Comment: Docs: https://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/entries/